# Laravel semicolon issue while dealing in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to get the selected fields of the query from an outside array.

```
foreach($param as $key => $val){
            if($val == 'userId'){
                $string .= "adminusers.id, ";
            }
            if($val == 'name'){
                $string .= "CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) as name";
            }
        }
```

My query is right below;

```
$where = '1';
$resultSet = UserAdmin::whereRaw($where)
                ->addSelect(array($string))
                ->groupBy('adminusers.id');
```

However, I received this :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stmd_adminusers.id, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `stmd_adminusers`.`id, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)` as `name` from `stmd_adminusers`

Comment: why is `whereRaw($where)` ?

Comment: @C2486 will include more option later during development time

Comment: what happen if only `$val == 'name'`  exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use Some Mysql native function you have to use `DB::raw()`

```
$resultSet = UserAdmin::whereRaw($where)
                ->addSelect(array(DB::raw($string)))
                ->groupBy('adminusers.id');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what happen if only `$val == 'name'`  exist ? will `groupBy` work ?

Comment: Yess as for as you not using strict mode

Answer (score 2):

You can use `->selectRaw($string)` instead:

```
$where = '1';
$resultSet = UserAdmin::whereRaw($where)
                 ->selectRaw($string)
                 ->groupBy('adminusers.id');
```

This has the advantage over using `->addSelect(DB::raw($string))` that you can (optionally) add a second parameter `$bindings`; which will protect you from SQL injection attacks more than using `DB::raw()` would.